# is there a way to get the character count in a string? in obj c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hii every one

is there a way to get the character count in a string in obj c?

like how does the SMS app determine how big of a bubble the text view sends and receives? thanks a lot

Comment: I don't think you care how many characters there are in the string, I think you should be asking how the UI knows how wide (in pixels) to draw a label :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
NSString *str = @"Hello World!";
NSUInteger len = str.length;
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a `NSString` then

```
[string length];
```

Not sure if you are talking about multi-bytes characters

Answer (score 1):

If it is `NSString` then use `str.length`
If it is c string then use `strlen(cString)`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> length
> ```
>
> Returns the number of Unicode
>   characters in the receiver.
>
> ```
> - (NSUInteger)length
> ```
>
> Return Value
>
> The number of Unicode characters in
>   the receiver. Discussion
>
> The number returned includes the
>   individual characters of composed
>   character sequences, so you cannot use
>   this method to determine if a string
>   will be visible when printed or how
>   long it will appear.

```
NSLog(@"Length of your string is %d",[yourString length]);
```